# How quickly can I reapply for an Egyptian tourist visa after getting refused once?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, egypt

If I'm refused for Egyptian tourist visa, how long do I have to wait before applying again?

Comment: You do not need to wait. You need to fix the problems which caused the refusal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mention of a wait period on [official](http://www.mfa.gov.eg/english/ConsularServices/Pages/ConsularServiceDetails.aspx?ID=Visa%20Application) [pages](http://www.egyptianconsulate.co.uk/FAQ.php) [anywhere](http://www.egyptianconsulate.co.uk/Visas_SectionI.php). Of course it's hard to prove a negative, but if they don't mention it, it's likely not an issue.

You should definitely address the reasons your application was refused (missing documents etc) *before* applying again.